# How to display last six dates, java.util.Date?

Tags: java, date

I went to display the current date and the six (6) last dates

example :

```
02/11/2012
01/11/2012
31/10/2012
30/10/2012
29/10/2012
28/10/2012
```

to get the current day in JAVA I used :

```
Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
System.out.println("current day : "+sdf.format(date));
```

but how do I decrement the days ?

Comment: Your question isn't clear - the title talks about the "current week" but the question talks about the last 6 days. They're not the same thing in general. For example, on a Tuesday I wouldn't count "last Thursday" as being in the current week.

Comment: I see, offer to me an ideal title

Comment: So are you saying your question body *is* correct? In that case: "How can I display the last six calendar days?" or something similar. Btw, do you *have* to use java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar? Joda Time is a *much* cleaner API...

Comment: I use java.util.Date, but I want also one solution using java.sql.Date !

Comment: You're aware that `java.util.Date` doesn't uniquely identify *any* day, as it's just an instant in time? The same instant that I think of as Friday may be Thursday or Saturday for you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Calendar#add` method to substract a day, like:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date=cal.getTime();
System.out.println(sdf.format(date)); //remove line to display only the last 5 days 
for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
   cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,-1);
   date=cal.getTime();
   System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
}
```

Like Jon Skeet (soon Mr. 500k :) ) suggested, I too find the Joda Time API more cleaner and appropriate, even for such simple tasks:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();                     
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {                     
    System.out.println(dt.toString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
    dt = dt.minusDays(1);                         
}
```

Comment: @berber5 For Joda you can use: `new DateTime(sqlDate.getTime());` and for Calendar approach, you can convert using: `cal.setTime(sqlDate);`

Comment: @berber5 You can do something like: `new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis())`

Comment: I get this error: /*java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date*/ ... so can you give a complet exemple please

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18974/discussion-between-dan-and-berber5)

Answer (score 2):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
System.out.println("current day : "+sdf.format(c.getTime()));

// decrement 1 day
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);

// getTime() returns a java.util.Date
System.out.println("the day before : "+sdf.format(c.getTime()));

// getTimeInMillis() returns a long, which can be used to construct a java.sql.Date
System.out.println("the day before : "+sdf.format(new java.sql.Date(c.getTimeInMillis()));
```

And so on...

Comment: `java.sql.Date` is a subtype of `java.util.Date`, so that shouldn't make a difference I suppose.

Comment: I get this erro when i try to cast : java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date